# Why is docs.count=0 in Elasticsearch, when uploading a Json-file?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I've got a JSON-file (test2.json), with data that looks like this:

```
{"index":{"_index":"wiki","_type":"data","_id":1},
 "mappings": {
  "doc": {
   "properties": {
    "curr": {"type": "text"},
    "n": {"type": "integer"},
    "prev": {"type": "text"},
    "type": {"type": "text"}
   }
  }
 }
}
{
    "results": [
    {
        "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"",
        "n": 43,
        "prev": "other-external",
        "type": "external"
    }
    {
        "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"",
        "n": 1569,
        "prev": "other-search",
        "type": "external"
    }
    {
        "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"",
        "n": 11,
        "prev": "other-internal",
        "type": "external"
    }
    ]
}
```

I get this data into Elasticsearch by using this command:

> curl elastic:elastic@localhost:9200/wiki -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d @test2.json

When I open up the Management in Kibana, I cannot find any index named "wiki", so I googled and someone said that it could be due to Elasticsearch not having any documents in it.

So I looked up at the Management-Elasticsearch section and truly "docs count" is zero.

[image: docs.count=0]

The question is now: how do I get Elasticsearch/Kibana to read my data from the file correctly? The mapping is accepted, as well as the index.
I just don't understand, why the "results" are not seen as a document.. Do I have to have another structure in my file?

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have copied your bulk command? the header section is wrong.
I never seen also the mapping clause inside an es dump. Are you sure that is possible?
According the `documentation` -  [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/_batch_processing.html):

- you should create your mapping for your index
- then you create a json dump - have a look [here](https://qbox.io/blog/understanding-bulk-indexing-in-elasticsearch) for json format guide, and [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/cirrussearch/current/enwiki-20190114-cirrussearch-content.json.gz) you can look the format of the wikipedia production elasticsearch dump
- then you index your dump, with a curl bulk command that according the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-bulk.html) is:

  `curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST   localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@test2.json"; echo`

Comment: Hey! I'm totally new to pretty much everything concerning the ELK stack, so I'm trying to test other examples by trial-and-error. The mapping passed inside the document "worked". At least I found the settings when I inspect the "wiki" index in Kibana. I saw that every example has the structure {index...}\n{fields..}\n{index...}, but I have to pass my example in the structure I have (at least the results-part), because I've got nearly 40000 of these.. Do you happen to know, if I can put the data inside without rewriting every {} to a one-liner and put an {index...} before every line?

Comment: In the meantime I wrote an python-script, that converts the data in the correct structure. Thank you for claring things up for me! I did not understand "bulk", but with your links its clear now :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. About a python script that creates the json structure for dump, please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228216/how-to-improve-elasticsearch-performance/54233233?noredirect=1#comment95424174_54233233